# How can I forward a port permanently (as a service) to a remote machine and still control access?

Tags: windows-server-2003, smtp

- I want to forward `localhost:25` to `our.isps.mail.server:25`.
- I don't want to set up a relay because I don't need complex rules or local queues of mail.
- I want dev applications to talk to localhost as if it were the smtp sever as that's what our live apps do.
- I need to restrict access to the forward to only localhost so that it is not open to the 'net, nor any other device on our LAN.
- It needs to be a service so it runs all the time and starts at boot.
- I know about *routing and remote access* but I don't want to use that because it asks me to disable the firewall.

Comment: It would be vastly better to get the devs to make the setting configurable. That way they can run their tests properly without having to screw about with the server settings. In general all it takes is a simple if/then on a flag that determines whether or not it's a test build. I feel sorry for you if your devs haven't been able to work that out for themselves.

Comment: @John. No need to be a patronising prick. This was really just fine tuning to make deployment quicker. There's always a constant defined to let the code know whether it's running on dev or live. I think it's pretty untidy having `if` statements all over the place and/or two sets of variables for things, hence trying to reduce the use of alternate code paths. I thought it was well understood that dev and live environments should be as similar as possible.

Comment: if that's how you (very incorrectly) read my comment you're going to find it tough going on SF.

Comment: @John There you go again. The last sentence "I feel sorry for you if your devs haven't been able to work that out for themselves." made a fairly foolish assumption and was patronising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is hardly an ideal thing to do.  Consider setting up your Dev machine the same way your production server is setup.

One way to do what you are asking for:
On the localhost Server2003 box, setup an smtp server in IIS6 and use a "Smart host".  It's in the "Advanced" settings on the "Delivery" tab of the SMTP server's properties. Set that to the name of the desired destination mail server.  Then deliberately open the firewall settings and don't allow incoming smtp traffic.

Another way thanks to @Stephen-Thompson is to use netcat for nt:  [NetCat](http://www.securityfocus.com/tools/139)

Comment: I highly recommend the IIS6 SMTP server option which I do on all servers needing SMTP.  This ensures it's as close to production as possible, in that your localhost will queue mail from the local app and try to forward.  It's a 5min setup like @G-Koe says and doesn't open any holes by default.  Even if 25 is allowed in, it's not an open relay by default.

Comment: Production servers are Linux machines.

Comment: Thanks, that worked a treat. I am curious to know if that is actually more like a linux production server where localhost is the actual mail server. Previous comment was just to discourage any more complicated live server configs.